# my Google Guice method interceptor doesn't execute but Why?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

So I am testing a simple Google Guice interceptor -

My Annotation -

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AppOpsOperation {

}
```

My Interceptor

```
public class AppOpsOperationDecorator implements MethodInterceptor {

    private ServiceCallStack callStack = null ;

    @Inject
    public void setServiceCallStack(ServiceCallStack stack ){
        callStack = stack ;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {

        // Retrieve the call stack 
        // exclude service population if caller service is the same service 
        // else push the current service onto top of stack 

        System.out.println("Intercepting method  -- ::  " + arg0.getMethod().getName());
        System.out.println("On object             - ::  " + arg0.getThis().getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("On accessible object  - ::  " + arg0.getStaticPart().getClass().getName());
        return invocation.proceed();
    }

}
```

And now my Service interface and method

```
public interface MockCalledService extends AppOpsService {

@AppOpsOperation
public String methodOneCalled(String some);

@AppOpsOperation
public String methodTwoCalled(String some);
}

public class MockCalledServiceImpl extends BaseAppOpsService implements MockCalledService {

@Override
@AppOpsOperation
public String methodOneCalled(String some) {
    System.out.println("MockCalledServiceImpl.methodOneCalled()");
    return this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "methodOneCalled";
}

@Override
public String methodTwoCalled(String some) {
    System.out.println("MockCalledServiceImpl.methodTwoCalled()");
    return this.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "methodTwoCalled";
}

}
```

And my Guice test module

```
public class MockTestGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {

    bind(ServiceCallStack.class).toInstance(new ServiceCallStack());

    AppOpsOperationDecorator decorator = new AppOpsOperationDecorator() ;

    requestInjection(decorator);

    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(AppOpsOperation.class), 
             decorator);

    bind(MockCalledService.class).toInstance(new MockCalledServiceImpl());
}

}
```

This interceptor doesn't execute when I run the test below -

```
public class AppOpsOperationDecoratorTest {

private Injector injector = null ;

@Before
public void init(){
    injector =  Guice.createInjector(new MockTestGuiceModule());
}

@Test
public void testDecoratorInvocation() {

    MockCalledService called = injector.getInstance(MockCalledService.class);

    called.methodOneCalled("Test String");

}

}
```

Can you please highlight what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering after finding the real reason. Its so simple that its really tricky.

Method interception only works if you bind the interface with the class and not an instance of this implementation.

so instead of `bind(MockCalledService.class).toInstance(new MockCalledServiceImpl());`

we should write `bind(MockCalledService.class).to(MockCalledServiceImpl.class);`

Seems instances are not proxied :(

Comment: Should be `to(MockCalledServiceImpl.class)`, not `toInstance`.  And yes, method interception is implemented by generating a subclass at runtime, so it can't apply to arbitrary instances.

Comment: I relate to the reason but its quite possible to implement a proxy delegate to be used for any and all instances of a specific type if we want to. What would be the challenges do you think ?

Comment: For one, it would be impossible to have any final methods because they couldn't be overridden with a delegating implementation.

Comment: I don't see this limitation being specific to instance binding though. Final methods will prevent interception even if it was a class binding. isn't it ?

Comment: Well when proxying a class, Guice only has to override methods that get intercepted.  To proxy an instance, Guice would have to override *all* methods (`@Override public int foo() { return delegate.foo(); }` for example).

Comment: Another reason is that `toInstance()` bindings are guaranteed to be identically equal (with `==`) to the provided instance, and changing that would backward incompatible.

Comment: @TavianBarnes that sounds accurate